# Getting RecoverableSecurityException while deleting file on Android API 29 and 30 with requestLegacyExternalStorage = true in AndroidManifest

Tags: android, scoped-storage

Below is AndroidManifest file code

```
<application
    android:name=".application.SomeApp"
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:largeHeap="true"
    android:networkSecurityConfig="@xml/network_config"
    android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
    android:resizeableActivity="true"
    android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true"
    android:theme="@style/THEME_DEFAULT_BLUE_ACCENT">
```

Delete file code

```
val result = CommonApp.getContext().contentResolver.delete(fileForAction.uri,
                        "${MediaStore.MediaColumns._ID} = ?", arrayOf(fileForAction.id.toString()))
                if(result > 0){ successDeleted++ } else { failedDeleted++ }
```

In above code fileForAction.uri is specific video file uri example: "content://media/external/video/media/23"

I have tested this on Android API level 29 and 30 both. But getting android.app.RecoverableSecurityException: com.packagename.someapp has no access to content://media/external/video/media/23

As I read on this documentation https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/shared/media#remove-item

**If scoped storage is unavailable or isn't enabled, we can remove files that other apps own without handlling RecoverableSecurityException.**

Comment: What is your question? The documentation shows [using the `RecoverableSecurityException` to obtain permission from the user](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/shared/media#update-other-apps-files).

Comment: My question is why I am getting RecoverableSecurityException while deleting a file when I opted for disabling scoped storage by providing android:requestLegacyExternalStorage = true in AndroidManifest.

Answer (score 1):

> why I am getting RecoverableSecurityException while deleting a file when I opted for disabling scoped storage by providing android:requestLegacyExternalStorage = true in AndroidManifest

You are not deleting a file. You are deleting an entry from `MediaStore` that represents a piece of content. `android:requestLegacyExternalStorage = "true"` has nothing to do with deleting an entry from `MediaStore`.

Comment: Then how can I delete a file in android?

Comment: @Himanshu: Follow the documented instructions to use the `RecoverableSecurityException` to gain permission. Then, if the user grants permission, re-try your delete operation. Your approach is fine. Your question was about why you were getting a `RecoverableSecurityException`.

Comment: Actually I was trying to delete multiple video files, So how could I gain permission for all files in one go?

Comment: @Himanshu: On Android 10, that is not an option. On Android 11, you can use `MediaStore.createWriteRequest()` to request permission for several `Uri` values at once. In [this sample project](https://gitlab.com/commonsguy/cw-android-r/-/tree/vFINAL/VideoTagger), I am modifying multiple video files rather than deleting them, but the principle is still the same.

Comment: You are right on android 11 we can make a bulk delete request but below Android 11 I was trying to achieve it by disabling scoped storage by giving android:requestLegacyExternalStorage=true but I was getting Recoverable security exception. Tell me If I am doing wrong.

Comment: @HimanshuL: `android:requestLegacyExternalStorage=true` is for filesystem APIs (`File`, `FileInputStream`, etc.). You do not get a `RecoverableSecurityException` from those APIs. You are not using those APIs. You are using `MediaStore`, and, as I wrote in my answer, **`android:requestLegacyExternalStorage = "true"` has nothing to do with deleting an entry from `MediaStore`**.

Comment: No, I think here is some understanding gap. Please read this documentation.  https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/shared/media#remove-item

Comment: @Himanshu: That code snippet has nothing to do with `android:requestLegacyExternalStorage`.